# How do you add an image into a database?

Tags: mysql

I'm building a blog with a cms and I've created a database using MySQL of the articles I want to show.  I want to also add an image to each of these articles so that they will show up on the site.  How do I go about adding an image into the MySQL database?

Comment: `base64_encode` the raw file contents?

Comment: Normally you should store your images in a folder and the url of each image in your database.

Comment: There are a couple of approaches, with pros and cons either way.  They generally boil down to: 1) Store the image in the table as a byte array (a blob column); 2) Store the image on the file system (file systems are really good at storing files) and store a reference to it in the database (file path or some other identifier).

Comment: @David I would have definitely said "and store a reference to it in the database (databases are really good at storing strings)"